# Nuxt wont render true data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I don't know what the problem is I don't know why
it goes straight to

```
'This is empty'
```

When this code `viewDetails[0]` is not empty

```
fullName() {
      return this.updateData?.viewDetails?.mock_name
        ? this.updateData.viewDetails[0]?.mock_name
        : 'This is empty'
    },
```

I expect that the output will be the data inside `viewDetails[0]` which is a name of a person and should not go to `This is empty` because `viewDetails[0]` has data in it.

Comment: Remove the optional chaining, you'll see why something is null/undefined. Also, please share how the `updateData` looks like/is coming from. Use your Vue devtools too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, `this.updateData.viewDetails` is an array, right?

So `this.updateData?.viewDetails?.mock_name` never exist, you're trying to access `mock_name` on an array, not an item of this array. i.e. you forgot the `[0]`.

Just do:

```js
fullName() {
   return this.updateData?.viewDetails?.[0].mock_name || 'This is empty'
},
```

Comment: Assumption is real. :P